# libhttp2 location for '.cache'

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up a django site, one that uses the oauth2client library, and therefor libhttp2.

Everything seems to work just fine, in the development standalone server, but when I try to hook it up to apache using mod_wsgi, I keep getting this one error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '.cache'
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  91.                         request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  215.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  244.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  239.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/django/prodapps/urls.py" in <module>
  5. admin.autodiscover()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  24.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in <module>
  141. admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in register
  90.             validate(admin_class, model)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/validation.py" in validate
  20.     models.get_apps()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py" in get_apps
  115.         self._populate()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py" in _populate
  61.                 self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py" in load_app
  78.             models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/django/prodapps/gn/models.py" in <module>
  6. from oauth2client.django_orm import CredentialsField, FlowField, Storage
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth2client/django_orm.py" in <module>
  28. from oauth2client.client import Storage as BaseStorage
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py" in <module>
  63.   CACHED_HTTP = httplib2.Http('.cache')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in __init__
  1073.             self.cache = FileCache(cache)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py" in __init__
  687.             os.makedirs(self.cache)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.cache'
```

So, seems like a simple problem - figure out where the this `.cache` directory is located, and give the webserver access to it, right?

Well, no - when I use the devserver, the .cache is right there in my tree.  But that doesn't seem to be the case with apache?

So where does this get set? How do I adjust it, or at least find out where it's trying to be created, so I can grant access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the oauth2client code for Django - it has a poorly written check for whether it can access the filesystem, along with a hardcoded relative path for the cache directory:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=75

Comment: Right. So my options are either hack oauth2client to fix this broken check, or symlink /.cache to something like /tmp/cache? Bah.